# Nexus One and Droid Razr have Same Qualifiers

Tags: android, qualifiers

I'm developing an app right now and I'm having trouble with two formats for my main menu.  I'm trying to make my app work with as many phones as possible, yet the Nexus One and Droid Razr, as far as I can tell, have the same qualifiers yet different sizes.

Am I missing something here?  They both follow the layout-normal-hdpi qualifier for my main_menu.xml

Is there another way I can distinguish them?  I'm using "dip" in my xml to separate buttons and the buttons leave the screen on the Nexus One.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josephus Villarey was correct. The simple solution was to use weights instead of hard-coding the positions of the objects.